# Drupal session help needed

Tags: php, drupal

I am working on a drupal based website. I am creating a shipping solution to be added to the drupal app. we want to use a common login for both shipping solution and drupal . how can we manage the session of drupal with the shipping ?

regards
sd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $_SESSION variable works quite well. You can store stuff in there and retrieve it on the page load and, like magic, it persists (thanks to code in session.inc).